# Exporting tables to html with fixed header when scrolling

Tags: org-mode, org-export, html

I have a rather tall table (200-300 lines) being exported to html.  It would be nice to have the header visible at all times when scrolling to the lower entries.

So far no googling has turned up a builtin solution, although [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29812382/5754992) shows how it can be done in general using only css.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a question about emacs behavior as much as it is about html and css.  Org mode adds several custom css classes, and these as well as standard css classes can be modified (see http://orgmode.org/manual/CSS-support.html).

The easiest way to modify this is by using `#+HTML_HEAD:` in the file, with appropriate html.

```
#+HTML_HEAD: <style type="text/css"> thead tr{display:block;} tbody{overflow:auto;display:block;height:90vh;} </style>
```

will give the desired behavior with tables, although it would be good to move to a css file if it gets much more complex.